# CSS Noob Could really use some Skilled help with layout and positioning

Tags: css, xhtml, layout, positioning, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stacking Divs with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062783/stacking-divs-with-css)

Im kinda new to CSS have been using tables for my html for years, Im trying to figure out how I can nest divs or stack them inside the content section of a 3 column layout. with tables I'd just do a new TR but if I float another div into the content line line it will appear parallel or vertically to content, instead of under it. is there another way to do this or am I missing the point of Divs here?

```
  <div id="header">Header</div>
  <div id="leftcolumn">Left Column</div>
  <div id="content">Content</div>
  <div id="footer">Footer</div>
```

Comment: You may want to try asking CSS questions on `doctype.com`.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062783/stacking-divs-with-css Mods, please act accordingly.

Comment: @Steve: This site is full of CSS questions. It's all part of development. Besides, nothing against doctype.com, but it doesn't compare favorably with SO for the technical aspects of this kind of question.

Comment: I don't mind either way, and I would also like to prevent overfragmentation of the Stack Exchange sites. But the FAQ reads "Web design and HTML/CSS layout, and your job title is 'designer', ask on Doctype."

Answer (score 1):

If you nest something inside `#content` and apply `clear:both` to it then it will appear beneath the content in `#content`.

Answer (score 1):

See the following articles from the Opera Web Standards Curriculum:

- [Floats and clearing](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/35-floats-and-clearing/)
- [CSS Static and relative positioning](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/36-css-static-and-relative-positioning/)
- [CSS Absolute and fixed positioning](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/37-css-absolute-and-fixed-positioning/)

Answer (score 1):

To have a floated element appear under another floated element, set `clear: both;` on that element.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better asking this on http://doctype.com/.

You need to clear your floats by using the {clear:left} rule or simply remove the floats. Read up on the the difference between inline and block elements and how you can manipulate them using the display property.

Comment: As a note, doctype.com closed as of February 15, 2013. [Read more about it](http://blog.doctype.com/doctype_is_closing_on_the_14th_1).